# Payara JDBC Connection Pool throws exception after applying SSL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, payara

I'm using Payara's JDBC Connection Pool for a long time and it is working great by using the following setting :

- user : xxxx
- password : xxxxxx
- url : jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.101:3306/webdb
- characterEncoding : utf8
- useSSL : false
- autoReconnect : true

I haven't applied SSL because it is located at the same network. However, I need to migrate the MySql server to the remote network and I would like to upgrade the security of connection.

- url : jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/webdb (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the public ip)
- useSSL : true
- verifyServerCertificate : false (the cert is not checked because the
  cert has not yet prepared)

However, I received the following error:

> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
> at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
> at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.flush(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:251)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:89)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T10CertificateVerifyProducer.produce(CertificateVerify.java:509)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:436)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHelloDone$ServerHelloDoneConsumer.consume(ServerHelloDone.java:173)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:178)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
> ... 97 more
> ]]

I can't confirm which setting or library causes this problems but the connection should be fine because I can connect the remote database by using Workbench (with SSL) and Payara JDBC Pool (Without SSL).

I have tried different setting but I am still can't get it working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm. "Broken pipe" diagnostic often refer to socket to be closed at DBMS. To be shure that is it Payara issue you could check MySQL log. May be cause could be found there?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, setting the property `fallbackToSystemKeyStore` of `MySQL Connector/J` to `false` solved the problem.